# DOS: how to get current country code or code page in Turbo C

Tags: locale, dos

How to get some locale-specific information where the country can be detected? E.g. current country code, keyboard layout or code page in Turbo C in **DOS** environment?

If that is not possible with Turbo C library functions, some BIOS calls could do that (INT 21)?.

KEYB program is able to show e.g. keyboard layout. That would be more than enough for my purposes:
https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/KEYB

Answer (score 3):

Use [INT 21h, AX=6501h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-3163.htm). Here's code for Turbo C:

```
#include <dos.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct country_info_buffer
{
  unsigned char info_id;
  unsigned short buffer_size;
  unsigned short country_id;
  unsigned short code_page;
  struct COUNTRY country_info;
};

int main()
{
  /* Registers for INT21 call */
  union REGS regs;
  struct SREGS sregs;
  /* Output buffer */
  struct country_info_buffer info;

  /* Get current value of segment registers */
  segread(&sregs);

  /* Get extended country information / general internationalization info */
  regs.x.ax = 0x6501;
  /* Global code page */
  regs.x.bx = 0xFFFF;
  /* Current country */
  regs.x.dx = 0xFFFF;
  /* Size of output buffer */
  regs.x.cx = sizeof(info);
  /* Pointer to output buffer goes to ES:DI */
  sregs.es = FP_SEG(&info);
  regs.x.di = FP_OFF(&info);

  /* Call int21 */
  intdosx(&regs, &regs, &sregs);

  if (regs.x.cflag)
  {
    printf("Call failed, ax=%d\n", regs.x.ax);
    return 1;
  }
  printf("Country code: %d, Code page: %d\n", info.country_id, info.code_page);
  return 0;
}
```

Btw. Ralf Brown's Interrupt List is great resource for DOS system calls. Too bad it stopped being maintained even before DOS ran out of favors, so some "newest" stuff isn't described there.

Comment: Excellent answer. Unfortunatelly DOSBox does not seem to provide useful country or code page information. The returned information was 1 + 437 (US country and code page). The current keyboard layout might be the only useful source for detecting the country.